# In rails 4 what is the correct way of using .where with associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in rails 4 and I am trying to perform:

```
User.properties.where(:property_id => 2).first
```

This produces an sql error which I understand and know why I cannot do it. But I just want to know the correct way to find by a foreign key with the :has_many associations in Rails 4.

Similar to this (which obviously works):

```
Property.where(:id => 1).first
```

Comment: What is the SQL error?

Comment: No such column exists. Which is not true, the table has a user_id, property_id.

Comment: How come you can't do `Property.find(2).user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.joins(:properties).where('properties.id' => 2).first
```

If you want to eager load the properties the use `includes` instead of `joins`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `where` is in terms of the `properties` table, which I'm guessing doesn't have a `property_id` column.

You could do this:

```
user.properties.where(id: 2).first
```

A better way would probably be this, though:

```
user.properties.find(2)
```

Comment: .find is deprecated in Rails4. The table is a has many through association.

Comment: Really? It's not marked as deprecated in my documentation. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ohhh, I just realised what the question actually was. Silly me.